# Hibernate batch update: need to know the failed statement

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, batch-processing

I have a code looking like this:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
try {   
for ( Customer customer: customers ) {
    i++;
    session.update(customer);
    if ( i % 200 == 0 ) { //200, same as the JDBC batch size
        //flush a batch of inserts and release memory:
        session.flush();
        session.clear();
    }
}
} catch (Exc e) {
        //TODO want to know customer id here!
}   
tx.commit();
session.close();
```

Say, at some point session.flush() raises an DataException, because one of the fields did not map into the database column size, one of those batch of 200 customers. Nothing wrong with it, data can be corrupted, it's ok *in this case*. BUT, I really need to know the customer id which failed. Database returns meaningless error message, not stating what was the params of the statement, etc. Catched exception also does not contain which customer did fail, only the sql statement text, looking like  'update Customer set name=?'

Can I somehow determine it using the hibernate session?  Does it store somewhere the information about last entity it tried to save down?